# get max salary from different dept without using group by, joins

Tags: mysql, sql

```
---------------------------
    dept | salary | name  
---------------------------
    1    | 10000  | ch1
---------------------------
    2    | 20000  | ch2
---------------------------
    2    | 25000  | ch3
---------------------------
    2    | 30000  | ch4
---------------------------
    1    | 15000  | xyz
---------------------------
    1    | 17000  | wer
```

I want to get max salary from each dept without using any subquery or join or group by.  Is this possible?

Comment: Just curious but *why* can't you use a `group by` here? Seems to me that using `group by` would make this task a great deal easier!

Comment: @TomMac because this table is just a dummy table , and my actual table contents some crusial data, if i use group by then that data is truncating.. thats why...

Comment: why would using a `group by` cause your data to be truncated? Now I really am intrigued...

Comment: Ah, perhaps you should tell us more as you can do a group by on a query, and you can join back to the original table(s) to get the rest of the data back, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't get the maximum salary by department without using `GROUP BY` or `JOIN` or a subquery, You also can't get it without using `SELECT` or `FROM`. It sounds like you are either playing code golf, or misunderstanding how GROUP BY or JOIN works. Any of the following 4 methods will give you the max salary by department, with the last 3 allowing you to retrive all your columns from your table:

**1.Simple Group By**

```
SELECT  Dept, MAX(Salary) AS MaxSalary
FROM    T
GROUP BY Dept;
```

**2.Group By and join back to main Table**

```
SELECT  T.Dept, T.Salary, T.Name
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Dept, MAX(Salary) AS MaxSalary
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY Dept
        ) T2
            ON t2.Dept = T.Dept
            AND T2.MaxSalary = T.Salary;
```

**3. Use LEFT JOIN/IS NULL**

```
SELECT  T.Dept, T.Salary, T.Name
FROM    T
        LEFT JOIN T T2
            ON T2.Dept = T.Dept
            AND T2.Salary > T.Salary
WHERE   T2.Dept IS NULL;
```

**4. Use NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT  T.Dept, T.Salary, T.Name
FROM    T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.Dept = T.Dept
            AND     T2.Salary > T.Salary
        );
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a47c/4)**

Comment: AS I TOLD WITHOUT USING ANY JOINS, IF YOU ARE USING JOIN, NO NEED TO WRITE THIS MUCH BIG QUERY!!!!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT DEPT, (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM TABLE_NAME TBL1 WHERE TBL1.DEPT= TBL2.DEPT) max_SAL
FROM TABLE_NAME TBL2

Comment: the above given is the self join!!! no need to use the biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig query as u answered!

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my answer, there are 4 independent, fairly small queries, not one Biiiiiiiiiiig query. The query you have suggested also contains a subquery, which you said in the question you did not want to use, it is also the same result as using GROUP BY but much less efficient. You can compare the execution plans on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a47c/250)